# How to color some text with .vtt and ffmpeg hardcode burn

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I have a .vtt subtitle that i wish to burn into a video, but i would like to display some of it another color.

For example :

```
This is IMPORTANT !
```

I would like the word IMPORTANT to be in red.

My `ffmpeg` code :

```
fmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "subtitles=sub.vtt" output.mp4
```

Using .vtt syntax, the only change I can have is *italic* with `<i>`.
`<c>`, `<c.red>`, `<ruby>`, etc.. aren't doing anything...

```
This is <i>IMPORTANT</i> !
```

Inside ffmpeg `-vf`, i can use `force_style` to change subtitle color, but i can only change the whole line, not part of it.

Thanks.

Comment: Convert subs to ASS format and use an editor like Aegisub to add mark-up. The subtitling engine ffmpeg uses to generate bitmap for hardcoding works only with ASS format. All other formats are converted to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !!! I've switched to .ass and i can now change the font size with `{\fs30}..{\fs0}`, and the color with `{\c&Hff00ff&}...{\c}`. Amazing!

Comment: Please answer your own question using the button below.

Comment: I was waiting for @Gyan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg delegates to `libass` the job of rasterizing text subtitles, and that library, as its name suggests, only works with ASS subtitles. When subtitles in another format are provided, ffmpeg will convert them to ASS. FFmpeg supports parsing only a limited amount of markup in VTT - `<i>` `<b>`, `<u>`.

So, convert subs to ASS format and use an editor like Aegisub to add mark-up.